# Integrating Fusion chart in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fusioncharts

I am changing My SPA application from Javascript to typeScript. In this project I have used Fusionchart JQuery plugin.
Now I have to integrate FusionChart in this type Script project. i have Added jquery.d.ts in my project but not able to figure out how can I use that to integrate.

Is there any way to that?

Comment: Post some sample javascript

Comment: Are you planning to use TypeScript with Visual Studio 2012 or command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly thanks to all.

I have done as follows:

I declared a class Names FusionChart in a separate ts file as follows:

```
declare class FusionCharts  {

    constructor(ChartType: string, ChartName: string, height: string, width: string);

    constructor(ChartType: string, ChartName: string, height: string, width: string, other: string);

    public setXMLData(ChartValues: string): any;

    public render(renderId: string): any;
    public static setCurrentRenderer(renderName: string): any;
}
```

after that I used the constructor of this class in my ViewModel backend .ts file as follows:

1. I added the reference of the FusionChart class.
2. Created he fusion chart object.
3. In compositionComplete I set the CurrentRenedrer to JavaScript(optional) and used the render method.

My code is as follows:

```
export class FinancialView 
{
   public column3DChart: FusionCharts;

   constructor() {
     this.column3DChart = new FusionCharts("Column3D", "myChartId", "300", "200");
     this.column3DChart.setXMLData("XML data");
    }
    compositionComplete() {
       FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
       this.column3DChart.render("chartdivId");
    }
}
```

Comment: das: Thanks for your extraordinary help. Now really I started convert to ts after seeing your code. It's amazing

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways in which you can get and use TypeScript.

1. MSI package for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
2. Command-line TypeScript compiler can be installed as a Node.js package.

Simply put TypeScript compiles all **.ts** files to **.js** files. It doesn't matter even if **.ts** files contain only JavaScript and no TypeScript at all, *as it is a superset to JavaScript*.

So just rename your JavaScript files to **.ts** and your app will work as it should. The added benefit is that you can use the power of TypeScript.